# Jenkins - get credential by using Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get the credential of Jenkins using Groovy code.

I cannot use `password = credentials('example')` because I need to fetch the credential in configuration groovy code (and not inside the pipeline source code).

Comment: have you tried withCredentials? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration Groovy code"?